# Which wordpress theme is compatible Optima Express theme (real estate inventory) plugin?

Tags: plugins, themes

I am using Optima [Express theme (real estate inventory)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/optima-express/) plugin for my wordpress website. And it is working perfect in admin are.
But as i started to use it in front end it is started to conflict with Jquery of current active theme. 
It does work with Twenty-Eleven, Twenty-Twelve but not the "[Striking](http://kaptinlin.com/themes/demo/?theme=striking)" and "[Karma](http://demo.truethemes.net/Karma-Wordpress/)"themes I wish to use with this plugin.

What should i do ? Should i go to everyplace in code and write [JquerynoConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) OR any better solution for this ?

All suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: This question would be *much* more useful if it were generalized to include Theme-Plugin script compatibility in general. As it is, it is bordering on being *too localized*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, the IDX plugin is coded properly with noconflict, but there is some inline JS in the themes that is not.  Wrapping those functions in

```
(function($) {
   // your functions here
})(jQuery);
```

will take care of the problem.  All JS in WordPress should be run in noconflict mode, so yes you'll need to go through the theme code and make sure it's functioning properly.